# show the equality of sections at right triangle

Tags: geometry

We have right triangle $ABC$ and squares $ABED$, $BCFG$ (see piture) lines $CD,AG$ intersects triangle sides at respectively points $H, I$ show that $HB=BI$

I tried to solve it looking for congruent triangles but I failed and don't have any other idea

[image]

Comment: $HI$ would be the hypothenuse of triangle $HBI$ so they would not be equal. Maybe HB=BI?

Comment: ohh sorry, you're right

Answer (score 1):

if you take $B$ as origin, and set $AB=a$ and $BC=b$ then a little coordinate geometry shows that:
$$
BH = \frac{ab}{a+b}
$$
since this is symmetric in $a$ and $b$ we must also have $BI = = \frac{ab}{a+b}$

for a more purely geometric derivation, consider the similar triangles $CBH$ and $CED$

Comment: yes, sorry, will correct the typo